# Issue with Bearer Token in JMeter for load test

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

We have 2 API and need to run 4 hours test and test need to run with 200 threads.
1) 1st API will generate bearer token and need to run with number of threads only i.e 200 and token will be valid for 1 hours.
2) second API will use token from 1st API and will run for 4 hours.

Note: we need not to be run 1st API more than 200 times.
how can be achieve in JMeter?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `1st API` request under the [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) if you want it to be executed only once however I can see one issue with this setup: after 1st hour of your test the token will expire and you will need to refresh it somehow so your `second API` will start failing after 1 hour and will fail for the next 3 hours.

I would rather put these 2 API requests to different Thread Groups and configure the `1st API` to run once per hour by adding i.e. [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) and configuring it to sleep for `3 599 000` milliseconds

[image]

The Bearer tokens can be passed between the Thread Groups in 2 ways:

1. Using [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function in 1st Thread Group to set the token value and [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function in 2nd Thread Group to read the value
2. Using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems incorrect. As when the token is generated for the first time, it pauses the current thread for the given wait time.
Is there a way, token can be generated every 1hr and used the test without any delayed Or pause time.